# Changing the width of individual pieces in pie charts in Swift 3.0 (using charts iOS)

Tags: swift, pie-chart

I have a piechart that displays two values: a total and a subtotal. It currently like this:

[the grey and red width is the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxpj4.png)

I need it to look like this:

[The grey part needs to be thinner, and then red, thicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oskr6.png)

I have set the attributes thusly:

```
let chart = PieChartView()

chart.data = pieChartData
chart.legend.enabled = false
chart.transparentCircleColor = nil

func setChart(labels: [String], pieSplit: [Double]) {
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<labels.count {
        let dataEntry = PieChartDataEntry(value : pieSplit[i], label : labels[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let dataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: self.totalSpent)
    dataSet.selectionShift = 7.0
    dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
    let chartData = PieChartData(dataSets: [dataSet])
```

So the chart is a uniform width, I assume the default width. Setting a userInteractionEnabled to 'true' changes the width of the grey part when clicked (becomes some default value thinner), but this isn't what I need. Any advice?